# JSDoc comments appearing differently when calling a function using redux and redux-toolkit action functions

Tags: redux, comments, redux-toolkit, jsdoc

I am trying out redux toolkit after many years of old-school from-scratch redux.  With `createSlice`, I defined my actions, with some JSDoc comments:

```
export const viewBuilderSlice = createSlice({
  name: "views",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    /**
     * Action to set all view layers in a single function call,
     * helpful for loading saved view into the map viewer
     */
    SetViewLayers: (state, action: PayloadAction<string[]>) => {
      // do reducer stuff
    },
    /**
     * Toggle a single layer on or off in the current view
     */
    ToggleViewLayer: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      // do reducer stuff
    },
  },
});

export const { SetViewLayers, ToggleViewLayer } = viewBuilderSlice.actions;
export const viewBuilderReducer = viewBuilderSlice.reducer;
```

Hovering over the second to last line, I see my JSDoc comments:

[image]

Then when I import the actions into the file to be called, on the import line, I still see my own comments[image]

But when I then go an *call* the function in a `dispatch`, the JSDoc comments I wrote seem to be overwritten by some generic redux-toolkit comments:

[image]

I thought maybe this was a function of using `createSlice` and exporting the destructured actions, so I tried defining actions independently using `createAction`:

```
/**
 * Action to set all view layers in a single function call,
 * helpful for loading saved view into the map viewer
 */
export const ToggleViewLayer2 = createAction<string>("views/TOGGLE_VIEW_LAYER");

export const reducer = createReducer(initialState, (builder) => {
  builder.addCase(ToggleViewLayer2, (state, action: PayloadAction<string[]>) => {
    // reducer stuff here
  });
});
```

But then importing this into another file to be used, the exact same problem occurs - on the `import` line, my JSDoc is preserved, but then calling `dispatch(ToggleViewLayer2)`, hovering over `ToggleViewLayer2()` shows redux's JSDoc comments.

There is the case where I define my own action creator function:

```
/**
 * Toggle a single layer on or off in the current view
 */
export const ToggleViewLayer = (payload) => ({
  type: "views/TOGGLE_VIEW_LAYER",
  payload,
});

// const reducer = createReducer(...)
```

In this last case, the JSDoc works properly, and is not overwritten by any redux JSDoc comments, but this sort of negates alot of the purpose of using redux-toolkit.

What gives here?  How and why is the external package's own JSDoc comments are overwriting my own, for explicitly documented functions, only when *calling* them?  Half the point of the JSDoc comment is to help myself or other devs understand what the function does, but it doesn't help when redux's JSDocs comment eclipses my own, or if JSDoc comments change between declaring a function and calling it.

#### Edit:

Digging into the redux typedefs, the return type of createAction in my use case is `ActionCreatorWithOptionalPayload`.  The type for that is:

```
/**
 * An action creator of type `T` that takes an optional payload of type `P`.
 *
 * @inheritdoc {redux#ActionCreator}
 *
 * @public
 */
export interface ActionCreatorWithOptionalPayload<P, T extends string = string> extends BaseActionCreator<P, T> {
    /**
     * Calling this {@link redux#ActionCreator} with an argument will
     * return a {@link PayloadAction} of type `T` with a payload of `P`.
     * Calling it without an argument will return a PayloadAction with a payload of `undefined`.
     */
    (payload?: P): PayloadAction<P, T>;
}
```

Apparently, `@inheritdoc` will force any other JSDocs being used to be overwrriten with the inherited doc.  However, removing `@inheritdoc` in the node_module code for @redux/toolkit does not solve the issue.  Removing the entire comment for this type *does*, but I don't really want to do that, I just want my own comment to take precedence.

Answer (score 1):

You documented the reducer, not the action creator.

Honestly, it's a miracle that the comment made it this far (from the reducer to the action creator) - TypeScript didn't preserve comments over mapped types in the past.

As for your question at hand: it attaches the comment to the type of the mapped property, but not to the explicit function overload.

See this example:

```
/** A function overload comment */
function foo(){}

const obj = {
    /** A property comment */
    foo: foo
}

// these two have different comments

obj.foo

obj.foo()
```

For your second case, it's the same. Your comment is attached to the constant, not to the function inside the constant.

Comment: Interesting.  I've not heard of overload comments.  If you look at my second codeblock, you'll see I explicitly `export const ToggleViewLayer2 = createAction('string')`, but this has the same behavior.  The intellisense for `ToggleViewLayer2` is *different* than the intellisense for `ToggleViewLayer2()`, i.e. different intellisense as a property vs as a function call.  Sorry I'm not trying to be dense but I truly don't understand why that's happening.  Your example works to show different comments for a property vs a function call, but I still don't understand *why*.

Comment: Searching for `overload comments` yields alot of results about overloaded *functions*, not overloaded *comments*.  I added a third example, which works as expected, but doesn't use utility functions from redux toolkit.  Does the return value of `createAction` have some JSDoc comment that is 'overloading' my own?  How might I leverage redux-toolkit utility functions, while having the documentation for my action functions persist through the codebase?

Comment: I might not have been clear enough: I'm a Redux Toolkit maintainer. We do not want to override your comment. If it were technically possible that your comment were there, we would make it happen. It is technically impossible.
We add a comment there so there is at least *some* comment, but by no means do we *want* to override your comment. If we had no comment there, there would not be any comment at all.

Comment: The point here is that this is not your function. This is a new function with a completely different call signature (from `(state, action) => state` to `payload => action`), and TypeScript does not "connect" the two in any way. What it does connect is the name of the property - and that one keeps the comment. But as soon as you're not looking at the property, but the *contents* of the property (a function), you get the comment of that content It will never be your comment, since you did not write that action creator by hand.

Comment: As for "overload comment" - a function can have multiple signatures/overloads, and every overload can have a different comment. 
This is an edge case with only one function signature/overload, maybe the term "signature comment" might be more fitting here.